# Winapi get Interlocked Singly Linked List Item, without Popping it

Tags: c, list, winapi, linked-list

I use a WinApi native Single linked list, i have a code example like so, that creates singly linked list, and nsert some data there:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Info 
{
    SLIST_ENTRY ItemEntry;
    DWORD dwUserId;
} INFO,*PINFO;


int main()
{    
    PINFO pInfo1 = __aligned_malloc(sizeof(INFO));
    pInfo1.dwUserId = 1;
    PINFO pInfo2 = __aligned_malloc(sizeof(INFO));
    pInfo2.dwUserId = 2;

    PSLIST_HEADER pListHead = __aligned_malloc(sizeof(pListHead));
    InitializeSListHead(pListHead);

    InterlockedPushEntrySList(pListHead, &(pInfo1->ItemEntry));
    InterlockedPushEntrySList(pListHead, &(pInfo2->ItemEntry));

    PINFO pInfoFirst = InterlockedPopEntrySList(pListHead); // gets pInfo2 into pInfoFirst, and removes it from list

    DebugBreak();

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

The thing is, that i don't need to pop the item, of course i can just insert it back, but that's really no needed overhead. I tried to access it like that:

```
PINFO pInfoFirst = (PINFO)&pListHead->Next;
```

But i get weird stuff in pInfoFirst. How can i do it?

Comment: If you peek at the item without popping it, then you run the risk of another thread popping and deleting the item while you are still using it. That's why there is no way to peek at the item without popping it. Popping it gives you control over the lifetime.

Comment: @RaymondChen what if i have a setup, where user specifies one thread, and i don't want to bounce it here and there? Can i use an alternative pre-made list without this synchronizations? ( no c++ allowed ). Of course i can just write my own in C, but would be nice if there is a system solution for this,

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to accomplish? What are your thread-safety requirements?

Comment: If you have only one thread, then you don't need a fancy interlocked list. A regular list would be sufficient.

Comment: Or if you have only one writer and multiple readers, maybe use a slim reader/writer lock.